# Не добавляется объект в массив

Tags: java

Есть некая программа, которая должна подключаться по ssh на сервер, выполнить там команду, получить результат и записать ответ в строковый массив.

Так вот, если я вывожу сразу ответ на экран - проблем не возникает. Но если этот ответ записать в массив или коллекцию - получаю NullPointerException.

```
    try {
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("uname -a");
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int j = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (j < 0) break;

                System.out.println (new String(tmp, 0, j)); //Работает
                answer[i] = new String(tmp, 0, j); //Не работает;


                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) break;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: `answer = new String[??]`

Comment: `NPE` может возникнуть только в случае, если `answer` не инициализирован.

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся. Да, дело было в том, что я объявил массив в начале класса, но не инициализировал его в ходе работы.
Но проблема в том, что я хочу его инициализировать только во время исполнения и заполнить нужными данными. Это возможно?

Comment: Хочу чтобы было что-то вроде такого:
```
String[] answer;
answer = new String(tmp, 0, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> answer;

answer = ArrayList<String>();
...
answer.add(new String(tmp, 0, j));
```

---

```
List<String> answerList = ArrayList<String>();
...
answerList.add(new String(tmp, 0, j));
...
answer = answerList.toArray(ArrayUtils.EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
```